# Focus item won't change in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, focus

I'm trying to adapt focus feature for my collectionView by [Focus on iPad keyboard navigation - WWDC21 - Videos - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10260/)

However, I met the problem that I can only focus on the first item, then the focus item won't change no matter I press up, down, left or right.

I checked the `UIFocusUpdateContext`, and found the `previouslyFocusedItem` is always equal to `nextFocusedItem`.

I thought maybe it's related to `preferredFocusEnvironments`, so I override it in cell and return collectionView, but it won't help

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you override the `canBecomeFocused` attribute of UICollectionView.

UICollectionView with `allowsFocus` to be set with `true` is unnecessary to override `canBecomeFocused`. Overriding it will cause odd behaviors like cannot change the focus item as you mentioned.